# Select remaining week dates with selected date using Swift3

Tags: swift, nsdate, jtcalendar

How to select remaining week dates when user select any date.
Below image shows what I want to achieve

[image]

I am using JTCalendar to show calendar values.

**Note: I can't show any code because I don't know how to code this problem.**

Comment: Its better to write issue on JTCalendar.